# Does a tool that concats, builds, and minifies your Node.js app into a single file exist?

Tags: node.js

Say I have a server-side app that I want to "publish" in a "compiled" version.
For Node.js, that would be:

- Concatenating the files together to obfuscate code structure
- Minifying to obfuscate code

Complications:

- CommonJS framework with `require`s - need to resolve paths
- 3rd party dependencies in `node_modules` - don't concatenate these
- "Assets" or basically any files that are not `require`d - need some sort of roster

Does such a tool exist?
Do you have recommendations on how to implement one?

Comment: Never heard of such a tool but I don't think it would be too hard to build. Especially if you just used some minifying code that already exists and added the concatenation of files to the tool.

Comment: Why would you want to obfuscate server side code?

Comment: read the first line of my question again

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but seems to be what you're after.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uglifier

You could then go

```
var nodeUglifier = require("node-uglifier");

new NodeUglifier("lib_compiled/test/testproject/main.js")).uglify().exportToFile("lib_compiled/test/resultFiles/simpleMergeAndUglify.js";
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's a node module. Am I supposed to include the source code for it?

Comment: I think the concept behind that module is great, but from the looks of it, it doesn't play well with es6 code.